# Piix4_SMBus: 000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller bus not enabled

Tags: boot, 15.10, vmware, vmware-player

I have been using Ubuntu on VMware Player; today when I logged into VMware, it showed updates available for Ubuntu 15.xx. I allowed the updates and after downloading all the packages it restarted automatically, but never booted back. It is throwing messages like

```
Piix4_SMBus: 000:00:07.3: Host SMBus controller bus not enabled
failed to start /etc/rc.local compatibility
```

Please describe a way to fix it!

Comment: Updated received was 'Wily Warewolf'

Comment: There has been a [fix for this problem](http://whitehatty.com/2012/09/30/vmware-fusion-5-fix-ubuntu-linux-12-04-host-smbus-controller-not-enabled/) for a while, but you need to access your Ubuntu installation 'hard disk' to edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add the line `blacklist i2c-piix4`  .  You may be able to do this by booting the VM from an ISO file for Ubuntu, and choosing 'Try Ubuntu'

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your quick response. Could you please elaborate the steps as I am not really good in doing this. How do I access Ubuntu Installation hard disk? Please provide the navigation. I am using VMware Player and installed Ubuntu on VMPlayer. Apologies for the trouble.

Comment: Had the exact same problem today with Debian 13 (Trixie) under VMWare Workstation 17, apparently after installing packet `webcam`. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/691737/614483) mainly gave me the trick!

Answer (score 11):

First, add this line in your vmx file to increase the boot time to 50s

```
bios.bootDelay = "50000"
```

Start the VM, hold the left shift key down, then hit Enter.

In the grub menu, choose **Advanced options for Ubuntu -> Recovery mode**.  Once the system boots, choose 'Root' to drop into a root shell.

In the root shell, enter the following commands

```
mount -o remount,rw /
nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

go down a few lines (almost anywhere) and enter the line

```
blacklist i2c-piix4
```

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Finally, enter the command

`reboot`

Comment: Thanks Charles for the detailed answer. I am able to resolve the first issue. I almost shouted 'Eurekha', but it did not boot yet :-(, still another issue is pending, Error: failed to start /etc/rc.local compatibility
see "sstemctl status rc-local.service" for details. Request you to provide your valuable solution. Appreciate your time & patience.

Comment: Sorry to hear continues problems.

Comment: Yeah...hopefully everything gets resolved with the solution you are going to provide. But blacklist i2c-piix4 is a good learning for me. Your crystal clear answer helped me in resolving that.

Comment: Did you happen to remove the vmtools from your virtual machine before updating?

Comment: 2nd question, if you execute `systemctl status rc-local.service` in the machine, what happens?

Comment: Initially I was not getting internet connection to the VM. So I have installed the vmtools and then internet connection was active. I have got the updates as the internet connection was active and I performed update. when I gave the command systemctl status rc-local.service i got the below:                                                                                                           Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local/service;static;vendor preset:enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local/service.d
          debian.conf
Active: inactive(dead)

Comment: Well, I don't see anything that is wrong there, but it's really gone beyond what I can help much with.

Comment: No problem Charles. Thanks a lot for your support. Have a great weekend.

Comment: I would request someone in the forum to help me with this. I am trying by exploring through various forums to close this, but no luck. Please need your support in closing this.

Comment: @MuraliG  You'll probably need to open a separate question, and you should try cross-posting into the [vmware community forums.](https://communities.vmware.com/welcome)

Comment: @MuraliG I did find another Ubuntu forum with a question related to this, where rc.local was being used to load the vmtools and caused problems.  Try this:  Log into the recovery mode as above, then `cd /etc` followed by `mv rc.local rc.local.old` and `touch rc.local` and chmod 755 rc.local`.  Then reboot.  This will copy your current rc.local into a different file, and create a new, empty, rc.local

Comment: Hi Charles, when I tried moving rc.local to rc.local.old I am getting error message "cannot move, read only file system". Should I change any permissions, please guide. Thanks a lot for coming back.

Comment: Ah - you forgot the part `mount -o remount,rw /` - when you start in the recovery mode, your computer is in read-only mode be default...

Comment: Dear Charles, I tried the above options but still no luck. I posted this in VMware forums also. https://communities.vmware.com/message/2552370#2552370. I have attached the screenshots also for your reference.

Comment: I know this post is old. but I have the same problem. when I do the @CharlesGreen said, my ubuntu is boot, but after some minutes (when I worked with it). It is hanging .how can I solve this problem? Help me plz :)

Comment: @H.Ghassami  I certainly do hope that you find an answer to your problem - I no longer run VMWare, but instead use KVM/QEMU to host virtual machines.  You could search, and post, your problem in the [vmware community forum](https://communities.vmware.com) perhaps, and receive some assistance.

Comment: Did not work for VMware Ubuntu 64-bit 18.04 on macOS

Comment: I had to additionally run `update-initramfs -u` after editing `blacklist.conf`

Comment: @TimD1 I don't think you should have to do that, but it has been a long time since I ran VMWare!

Comment: I too had to run `update-initramfs -u` only to find that I had made a small mistake in `/etc/fstab` - I had changed the root mount from `/` to `/i` - likely by pressing `i` in the `vi` editor :) When `update-initramfs -u` complained it could not find what disk to boot from, I knew to check `/etc/fstab`; removed the `i` from `/i`, re-ran `update-initramfs -u` (this time really necessary to set the correct root/boot patiation), and it all worked fine again. Also blacklisted the i2c-piix4 at the same time, which I now suspect was no the original issue, just a (now fixed) error during boot.

Comment: I know this forum is Ubuntu-related but, in case someone has the same problem under Debian (13), as it happened to me, the file to append is slightly different: `/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

The method above didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.10 and VMWare Workstation 12.5.1..

Boot into Ubuntu Recovery Mode --> drop into the root shell and open the kernel blacklist config file.

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then add this line into the file and save.

```
blacklist intel_powerclamp
```

I found this solution from this post:

https://websiteforstudents.com/question/student-question-resolve-ubuntu-16-10-piix4_smbus-host-smbus-controller-bus-not-enabled/

Answer (score 3):

At first, open *.vmx file from your VMware folder via notepad. Then add this line to the file and save it.

```
cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101"
```

The problem will be fixed.

Comment: This option worked for me, but only with one CPU -- had to reduce number of CPUs, before it worked. Now I can disable smbus in /etc/modprobe.d.  I tried blacklisting from grub but none worked - OpenSUSE Tumbleweed 20180124 - Thanks!

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm late to the party, the solution to your other problem (`failed to start /etc/rc.local compatibility` etc., as described in the later comments to Charles Green's answer) is most probably (at least was for me), to wipe old, incompatible `vmhgfs` (shared VM disk) settings/module, since they break a couple of things.

First, the module doesn't load if there are version mismatch etc. Remove `vmhgfs` from `/etc/modules`, and now the init should run properly.

Secondly, if you added a `fstab` entry for your `vmhgfs`, [`systemd-fstab-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html) generates a `systemd` startup task for it, also resulting in failed `systemctl` unit. Comment out or remove your `vmhgfs` line in `fstab`, and remove the relevant `mnt-*.mount` (e.g. `mnt-vmhgfs.mount`) files from your `/run/systemd/generator`. That should fix the 2nd part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by dropping into safe mode and running clean.

EDIT:

This was done holding shift when rebooting the VM. when in the grub go to "advanced options". Then in that menu run "clean"

Comment: Could you edit your answer and provide more detail about how to enter safe mode and run clean ?