# Ubuntu 18.04: Boot Freeze / Purple Screen Hangs

Tags: boot, 18.04, vmware, freeze

Just today when I started Ubuntu 18.04 (Linux Kernel 4.15.0-51) in VMware Workstation Player 14 (14.1.7) the boot freezes just before the login prompt. The mouse cursor is visible and the Ubuntu logo at the bottom center is just being rendered as is visible in the attached screenshot. (Depending on the exact moment of the freeze the Ubuntu logo appears more or less bright.)

I am able to boot if I enter recovery mode and simply resume the boot. However, I am not able to set the display resolution to the hosts' nor is the host's display device detected.

To resolve the issue I reinstalled the VMware tools as well as the `open-vm-tools`. I also tried to extend the "Unit" section of `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/open-vm-tools.service` with `Requires/After=graphical.target` to no effect. Lastly, I attempted to check the filesystem which failed:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
/dev/sda1 mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Finished, please press ENTER
```

Boot freeze on purple screen before login prompt:

[image: Boot freeze on purple screen before login prompt]

Comment: What happens if you press `F12`?

Comment: Nothing happens. It appears the system is completely stuck. Though I can shut down the guest properly.

Comment: When you in the grub boot loader, press `c` on the default Ubuntu target. There is a line `linux ... vmlinuz... quite splash`. remove this `quite splash` and boot the modified configuration. Make a screenshot of the output and add to your question.

Comment: I removed the "quite" at the end of the line (there was no "splash"). While I see a lot more output before the purple screen, the result is the same.

Comment: Can you post that output? It might help to identify the issue...

Comment: Is there a way to hide the purple screen or read the log after a recovery/resume boot? Otherwise, I am only able to get glimpses at the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after an update today.
Solution was to disable wayland:

[Unable to login to account in ubuntu 18.04 vmware workstation 15, after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149957/unable-to-login-to-account-in-ubuntu-18-04-vmware-workstation-15-after-update)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This resolved the issue for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact issue and it seemed like it has something to do with the graphics drivers. To temporarily fix it, I removed 3D acceleration from VMWare settings.

Go to VM->Settings->Display and uncheck Accelerate 3D graphics.

The Ubuntu VM now boots in normal mode and the screen resolution can be switched.

Now to fix 3D acceleration, you need to disable Wayland. Open up a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the line

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

This disables Wayland and enables you to turn on 3D acceleration again.

Comment: 3D acceleration did not have an effect in my case. Disabling Wayland (as root in recovery mode), as @tsp and you suggest did word.