# Ubuntu 18 stuck in the purple screen

Tags: 18.04, 18.10

I am using Ubuntu 18 on virtual host of Windows 10. Yesterday I got some updates so I applied them and today when I try to start the Ubuntu I am getting stuck in the purple screen.

Please help me my all data is on Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using?  You list Ubuntu 18 (*there is none,* Ubuntu Core 18 is closest though usually used headless), but then tag 18.04 & 18.10?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it's solution.

Step 1: Follow the steps 1 and 2 define in the article https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/

Step 2: Then use this article [Unable to login to account in ubuntu 18.04 vmware workstation 15, after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149957/unable-to-login-to-account-in-ubuntu-18-04-vmware-workstation-15-after-update)

I hope it will help for others